# SpaCy: Match part of Doc

Tags: pattern-matching, spacy

I tried to use SpaCy's [`Matcher`](https://spacy.io/api/matcher) to search a `span`, but it turns out I can't.

```
 Argument 'doc' has incorrect type (expected spacy.tokens.doc.Doc, got spacy.tokens.span.Span)
```

How can I search only a part of a `doc` then? Is there a simple way to convert a `span` to a `doc`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the `Matcher` expects to be called on `Doc` objects, not `Span` objects. But if you need to, you can use the [`Span.as_doc`](https://spacy.io/api/span#as_doc) method:

```py
doc = nlp("Hello world. This is a text.")
span_doc = doc[0:3].as_doc()
print(span_doc.text)  # 'Hello world.'
```

Note that this will create a **copy of the content**, so the resulting object isn't a view of the parent `Doc` anymore, but a completely separate object. In most cases, this shouldn't matter, but it's still important to keep in mind.